# how to get one number after calculation of distance between 2D matrices

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, vector, scikit-learn, word-embedding

I'd like to calculate document similarity by using word embedding models (w2v, glove)

so one document can be represented 257*300 matrix 
 ( 257(max number of document) * 300(pretrained embedding model dimension))

And now I try to calculate distance between all document.

When I use cosine similarity, euclidean or other vector calculation methods in scikit-learn.

But these methods return similarity matrix.

Is there any method to get one number after matrix distance calculation?

Or should I calculate average of all vectors in similarity matrix ? (I think this is not proper way to solve this problem..)

Comment: what does that one number mean? what do you plan to do with that number?

Comment: sorry, what am i trying to say is "one scalar" (not matrix/ vector value). I'd like to get distance btw all document matrix. And distance value hope to be scalar (ex.0.5321) If 2 documents are same, similarity could be 1.